# How to show a loading indicator in React / Webpack app for large javascript file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app with a set of large javascript files to download (several MB) using Webpack to bundle the files.  These files are not necessary on all pages, and I do not want to "preload" them unless the user explicitly starts the app.

I would like to show some sort of loading page or indicator when the JS files are downloading.  But, if the files are already downloaded and in the cache, I would like to skip that page.

How can I show a loading indicator on my React app?

Comment: I recommend you read this article first: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/